# How to sum the hours using two Date Fields and group them by the user id in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I feel like the task is straight forward but I am having hard time getting it to do what I want.

Here is a table in my database:

```
ID |Empl_Acc_ID |CheckIn                  |CheckOut                 |WeekDay    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | 2017-09-24 08:03:02.143 | 2017-09-24 12:00:00.180 | Sun   
2  | 1          | 2017-09-24 13:02:23.457 | 2017-09-24 17:01:02.640 | Sun
3  | 2          | 2017-09-24 08:05:23.457 | 2017-09-24 13:01:02.640 | Mon
4  | 2          | 2017-09-24 14:05:23.457 | 2017-09-24 17:00:02.640 | Mon
5  | 3          | 2017-09-24 07:05:23.457 | 2017-09-24 11:30:02.640 | Tue
6  | 3          | 2017-09-24 12:31:23.457 | 2017-09-24 16:01:02.640 | Tue
```

**and so on....**

I want to group **Empl_Acc_ID** by the same date and sum up the **total hours each employee worked that day**. Each employee could have either one or more records per day depending on how many breaks he/she took that day.

For example if **Empl_Acc_ID** (2) worked 3 different days with one break, the table will contain 6 records for that person but in my query I want to see 3 records with the total hours they worked each day.

Here is how I constructed the query:

```
select distinct w.Empl_Acc_ID, ws.fullWorkDayHours
from Work_Schedule as w
INNER JOIN (

        SELECT Empl_Acc_ID, fullWorkDayHours =  Sum(DATEDIFF(hour, w.CheckIn, w.CheckOut))        
        from Work_Schedule w
        GROUP BY Empl_Acc_ID

) ws on w.Empl_Acc_ID = ws.Empl_Acc_ID
```

This query does not quite get me what I need. It only returns the sum of hours per employee for all the days they worked. Also, this query only has 2 columns but I want to see more columns. when I tried adding more columns, the records no longer are distinct by **Empl_Acc_ID**.

What is wrong with the query?

Thank you

Comment: Little remark: `select DATEDIFF(hour, '10:01:00', '11:59:00')` will give you `1`, but man worked almost two hours

Comment: Ruslan, What do you recommend in this case?

Comment: use `minute`, then divide by `60.0`

Comment: Sure thank you man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  You just have to group by date and employee account.

```
select Employee.Empl_Acc_ID, FirstName, LastName, Username, 
convert(varchar(10), checkin, 101) as checkin, convert(varchar(10), 
checkout, 101) as checkout, sum(datediff(hour, checkin, checkout)) as hours
from Employee
inner join Employee_Account on Employee.Empl_Acc_ID = 
Employee_Account.Empl_Acc_ID
inner join Work_Schedule on Employee_Account.Empl_Acc_ID = 
Work_Schedule.Empl_Acc_ID
group by convert(varchar(10), checkin, 101), convert(varchar(10), checkout, 
101), Employee.Empl_Acc_ID, FirstName, LastName, Username
order by Employee.Empl_Acc_ID
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I have other tables to join!

Comment: JOINing other tables can change the output of this. Plus, if you include any of the other fields in your SELECT, you'll have to change your GROUP BY, also changing the output.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need self-join this table in that case, just group by casting the datetime field to date.

```
create table Work_Schedule (
ID TINYINT,
Empl_Acc_ID TINYINT,
CheckIn DATETIME,
CheckOut DATETIME,
WeekDay CHAR(3)
);


INSERT INTO Work_Schedule VALUES (1, 1,'2017-09-24 08:03:02.143','2017-09-24 12:00:00.180','Sun');
INSERT INTO Work_Schedule VALUES (2, 1,'2017-09-24 13:02:23.457','2017-09-24 17:01:02.640','Sun');
INSERT INTO Work_Schedule VALUES (3, 2,'2017-09-24 08:05:23.457','2017-09-24 13:01:02.640','Mon');
INSERT INTO Work_Schedule VALUES (4, 2,'2017-09-24 14:05:23.457','2017-09-24 17:00:02.640','Mon');
INSERT INTO Work_Schedule VALUES (5, 3,'2017-09-24 07:05:23.457','2017-09-24 11:30:02.640','Tue');
INSERT INTO Work_Schedule VALUES (6, 3,'2017-09-24 12:31:23.457','2017-09-24 16:01:02.640','Tue');




SELECT w.Empl_Acc_ID, 
       CAST(CheckIn AS DATE) [date], 
       SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, w.CheckIn, w.CheckOut)) fullWorkDayHours
FROM Work_Schedule w
GROUP BY w.Empl_Acc_ID, CAST(CheckIn AS DATE)

DROP TABLE Work_Schedule;

Empl_Acc_ID date    fullWorkDayHours
1   2017-09-24  8
2   2017-09-24  8
3   2017-09-24  8
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not group by date, that's the issue:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.Empl_Acc_ID, ws.fullWorkDayHours, ws.CheckInDate
  FROM Work_Schedule as w
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT Empl_Acc_ID, CAST(w.CheckIn AS DATE) AS [CheckInDate], fullWorkDayHours =  Sum(DATEDIFF(hour, 
w.CheckIn, w.CheckOut))        
    from Work_Schedule w
    GROUP BY Empl_Acc_ID, CAST(w.CheckIn AS DATE)

) ws on w.Empl_Acc_ID = ws.Empl_Acc_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of doing self join, it works fine without it:

```
Select distinct Empl_Acc_ID, Sum(DATEDIFF(hour,CheckIN,CheckOut)) As 
FullDayWorkHours from EMP2
where DATEPART(day,CheckIn)=DATEPART(day,CheckOut)
Group By Empl_Acc_ID
```